# NullPointer exception when using ListView

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I've got following code, which gets launched as a second activity:

```
public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

List<Sensor> sensors;
Sensor selectedSens;
SensorManager SensMng;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sensor);

    final ListView listSensors = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listvalues);


    SensMng = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensors = SensMng.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
    ArrayAdapter<Sensor> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Sensor>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sensors);
    listSensors.setAdapter(adapter);



}
```

Here's my XML file:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listvalues"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I keep on getting a nullpointer exception:

```
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ch.ethz.inf.vs.android.spurra.sensors/ch.ethz.inf.vs.android.spurra.sensors.SensorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893): **Caused by**: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1882)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at ch.ethz.inf.vs.android.spurra.sensors.SensorActivity.<init>(SensorActivity.java:24)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     ... 11 more
```

All I did was really just copy past from my main activity, plus adjusting the values. The main activity works without any problems, this one however doesn't. I've tried cleaning, rebuilding the project, to no avail.

Can anyone please tell me whats wrong?

Thanks,
Regards

Comment: while calling the adapter of an arraylist try to add android.R.id.text1 it has to be followed after the layout

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: How do I get the stack trace? Sorry I'm new at this.

Comment: You posted the first line of it.  If you keep reading the lines, you'll see "caused by".  Either paste all the lines down to "caused by" or the complete list.  It will tell you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: check whther u do have some sensor values. check if its null or not

Comment: @BananaCode you have part of the logcat in the blockquote above. But you are missing important parts. Copy/paste all of it in your post.

Comment: Posted the entire trace.

Comment: Are you sure the xml you posted is from `activity_sensor.xml`? It looks like your `ListView` is `null`. And what is at line 24?

Comment: Yeah it's from activity_sensor.xml. I've only omitted the default code which I put in comment.
Where do you mean line 24?
Thanks for the cleanup of my stack.

Comment: `**Caused by**: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1882)
10-03 21:46:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(9893):     at ch.ethz.inf.vs.android.spurra.sensors.SensorActivity.<init>(SensorActivity.java:24)`  See the very last bit?  `SensorActivity.java:24`  SensorActivity.java, line 24

Comment: What he means is which line of code is line 24, if you are using an IDE it should be quite easy to find the line number.

Comment: "...I've only omitted the default code which I put in comment", what do you mean by this, in Java, xml? It could be important. Count down 24 lines from the very top and tell me which it is. Or turn on line numbering and see which is at #24. But I'm pretty sure its where you are initializing your `ListView`

Comment: It was additional code I've left out, as I only wanted to post the code which I thought was relevant for the question. The line is following:  final ListView listVals = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listvalues);

Deleting it solves the problem. Does this mean I can only call findViewById once?

In the future I'll post the entire code, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No, you can call that as many times as you want but it will return `null` if the `View` you are calling in `(R.id.someID)` is in the xml you inflate in `setContentView()`. You do want to only post the most relevant code so that is good but I think there is something we aren't seeing here. We almost never want your full source.

Comment: I've declared " final ListView listVals = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listvalues);" as a field, so before running setContentView(). Once I've moved it into the actual function, it worked. So I assume that was causing it to return null?

Comment: `findViewById` has nothing to find if you haven't inflated (loaded) the layout using `setContentView` and will return null.

Comment: @BananaCode yes, I have posted an answer hopefully explaining it. I hope that helps.

Comment: It does. Thank you to all for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've declared "   final ListView listVals = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listvalues);" as a field, so before running setContentView(). Once I've moved it into the actual function, it worked. So I assume that was causing it to return null?

Yes. If you call `findViewById(R.id.someId);` before calling `setContentView(R.layout.someLayout);` it will `return null` because you haven't yet inflated your `layout` which contains the `View id` you are trying to find.

Basically, your `Views` exist inside of your `layout` so if you try to use `findViwById()` before you inflate your `layout` (usually with `setContentView()`) then there is nothing to find. So you will get `NPE` when you try to use like when you call a function on it.

Answer (score 0):

If your project has external jar files, go to Project->properties->order and export and select all external jar files. That should do the work.